# Stderr of child process not received when child process exits

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, child-process

We have a VS Code extension built in node that runs like so:

Our extension is a node process, it calls `child_process.spawn(...)`, with `pipe` option for the stdio. The child process' stdin and stdout are used to pass messages between the two processes.

Due to a bug in the child process binary, we see an issue where SIGSEGV error code is thrown by the binary. When we call into the process on the commandline and hit this error, we see the stack trace is dumped to stderr.

In the VS Code extension/node process, we see the handlers for the child process exiting are hit, however the handlers for the stderr output do not.

In other non-crashing scenarios, we see stderr output is correctly transmitted.

The implementation of spawning and handling the child process is reasonably complex, however it boils down to something like this:

```
child_process.ChildProcess childProcess;

startChildProcess() {
    this.childProcess = child_process.spawn(binary, args, {
      cwd: root,
      env: {...process.env, ...environment},
      // pipe stdin and stdout, and inherit stderr (unless parent know better)
      stdio: ['pipe', 'pipe', 'pipe'],
    });

    // set up stdin and stdout pipes here...
    
    this.childProcess.on('exit', (code, signal) => {
      // do something interesting when the process exits
      // THIS CODE BLOCK IS HIT
    }

    this.childProcess.stderr?.addListener('data', (errOutput) => {
      const errOutputStr = errOutput.toString();
      process.stderr.write(errOutputStr);
      // THIS CODE BLOCK IS NOT HIT WHEN THE ABOVE IS HIT
    })
}
```

As annotated in the example, the stderr output is not hit in the case of a SIGSEGV from child process.

What can I do to ensure the errors are output? VS Code, the extension process and the child process are all running on Mac OS

Comment: I have observed that `childProcess.stderr.eventNames() only seems to return `close` and `close` events in this instance, and not a `data` event. Not sure if this is expected.

The `end` event is being called, and the stream's state indicates nothing had been written